# How do I add class for time(clock)

Tags: javascript

I get date and clock.

```
var mydate = new Date();
var clock = tarih.getHours();
var minute = tarih.getMinutes();
```

And want this;

```
if (clock> 5) {
    add this class, if have id "menu" = "menu_edit" (i dont know how can i do)
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If 'menu' is id of element:

```
document.querySelector('#menu').className += " menu_edit";
```

**UPD:**

According to your comment:

```
document.querySelector('.class1').className += ' class2';
```

Or if there are several elements:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.class1');
elems.forEach = [].forEach;
elems.forEach(function(el){
    el.className += ' class2';
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector - about function.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp - about selectors.

Comment: Thx for answer. 
Just i want; 
If the morning(06:00-18:00) now, for example; <div class="class1">.
If evening(19:00-05:00) now; <div class="class1"> change to <div class="class1 class2">.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: I try this;
if (clock > 18) { document.querySelector('.menu').className += ' night'; } but doesnt work. Google Chrome says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of null".

Comment: Cannot read property 'className' of null.
It means that document have no elements with class 'menu'. Try document.querySelector('.menu') in console, you will see null, because current selector is not valid for your purpose. You said, there are id, so try document.querySelector('#menu').

Comment: I try document.querySelector('.menu') in console and console find that div.
Also i try document.querySelector('#menu') in console and console find that div again.
Because my div is this: <div class="menu" id="menu">

Comment: It means that this code will work, "Cannot read property 'className' of null" cannot appear if there are element corresponding to css-selector.

Comment: Okay, thx for the help :)
I try to learn Document.querySelector() looking that. https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: @vadimka - rather than pre-pending a space to the name of a class, before doing `elem.className += spacePlusClassName`, you should consider using the `.classList` object instead. It has `.add`, `.remove`,  `.contains`, `.item` and `.toggle` methods. So you'd instead type `elem.classList.add(className)` - this means you can never add the same class twice, dont have to do string manipulations and I'll bet, it's faster too. See more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this. Please see the comments for an explanation.

checkout https://babeljs.io/ for info on compiling ES6 to ES5

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('#menu')
const menuClasses = [
  'menu--morning', 
  'menu--afternoon', 
  'menu--evening'
]

// helper function to toggle classes like a radio button
// this uses currying to lock in the classes and element, but
// allow us to change the active class dynamically
const toggleClasses = (classes, element) => clazz => {
  element.classList.remove(...classes)
  element.classList.add(clazz)
}

// create the toggle function and pass in the classes and the element
const toggleMenuClass = toggleClasses(menuClasses, menu)

// run a timer every n seconds
const timer = () => {
  const date = new Date()
  // I'm using seconds for the example as you will see the change
  // but you should change this to hours
  const second = date.getSeconds()
  
  if (second < 20) {
    toggleMenuClass('menu--morning')
  }
  else if (second < 40) {
    toggleMenuClass('menu--afternoon')
  }
  else {
    toggleMenuClass('menu--evening')
  }
  
  // just to show the current time for the example
  menu.textContent = second
  // call the timer function again after 500 milliseconds
  setTimeout(timer, 500)
}
// init the timer on load
timer()
```

```css
#menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: 1s background;
  font-size: 5em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color:#fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100vh;
}

#menu.menu--morning {
  background: #AED6F1;
}

#menu.menu--afternoon {
  background: #ABEBC6;
}

#menu.menu--evening {
  background: #B95A75;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">clock</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I solved my problem with pHp.
Instead of adding class, i try take a different css page. Thanks for all things.
Have a nice day. :)

```
$clock = date('H');

if ($clock > 14) {
    echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/night.css'>";
}
```